# How can I apply the alpha-beta pruning algorithm to the "1-2 steal marbles" problem?

Tags: search, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I have the following problem called "1-2 steal marbles".

Initially, there are 6 marbles on the board. One of the players can choose to remove 1 or 2 marbles leaving 5 or 4. After that, the other player can do the same, choosing to take again 1 or 2 marbles from the board. The process continues until there is only one marble on the board. The player who wins is the one the leaves the last marble on the board. (For example: If there are 3 marbles and it's my turn, then I will choose to remove 2 to leave one in the board to win)

How can I draw the search tree that represents the application of the alpha-beta pruning to this "1-2 steal marbles" with 13 marbles? I would like to see the maximizer and minimizer nodes and the value at the nodes too.

Comment: Hi Zhengliang Chen, welcome to AI stack exchange! Please [see the tour](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tour) and look around to see how this site works. For your post, could you please give more explanation, what is your exactly question?

Comment: How to draw the decision tree about this example? Please give me the decision tree.

Comment: @malioboro Thanks for commenting and welcoming this new user. Just a quick note. Whenever you see a post that is unclear, off-topic, too broad, etc., flag it to be closed, so that other users can see the flag and also flag it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Do you know how minimax works? If not, I suggest you read about it first. If yes, do you know how alpha-beta pruning works? There's a nice example [http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~rosen/161/notes/alphabeta.html](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~rosen/161/notes/alphabeta.html) of the application of alpha-beta pruning. I suggest you read it first and I believe you can answer this question alone :)